# Function whose output is a list over matrix rows in R

Tags: r, list, apply

I have the next problem. I have a function f, whose output is a list with two elements. Let's say

```
f<-function(row, number){
#some procedures
p1<-vector1
p2<-vector2
return(list(p1,p2))
}
```

Now, I have to apply this function to 190 rows of a DB with a long number of columns a lot of times, so I'm looking for a function like "apply" that allows me to save in a list the output of the function for the 190 rows. I mean, a function whose output (applied over the rows of my DB) is something like below:

```
output[[i]][[j]] = f(row_i, number)[[j]]
```

I hope to have been clearly enough.

Notes:

1. It'd be awsome if the code would run in the less possible time, because, as I said, I have to do this procedure a lot of times.
2. I don't know if it's necessary to remove the "list" part from the function I define to obtain the result I'm looking for.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Try with `lapply(seq_len(nrow(data)), function(i) f(i, number))`

Comment: *awsome if the code would run in the less possible time"* is somewhat meaningless since you provide nothing about what the function actually does. (If I could provide something that executes any arbitrary function in less time, I would be set for life. The hard truth is that it depends heavily on the actual contents of the function and the composition of the data.)

Comment: What's the actual function? What does `number` represent and what do you do with it? This is a very general question without giving the details of your problem. "Applying a function over the rows of a data base with a long number of columns a lot of times" isn't very clear.

Comment: @akrun thank you so much. It's just what I was looking for. I'm just testing how much time it takes in my DB.

Comment: It's a little complicated function. Basically each of the two vectors are probability measures and I have to work with each of them.